# Can't access position on my list

Tags: python, list

i'm trying to extract some informations from a txt file, but after split a line i can only access de first position of the list. 
Anyone have a ideia why?

My txt file is like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="osmconvert 0.8.4" timestamp="2017-03-06T01:59:59Z">
    <bounds minlat="43.48" minlon="-79.7899999" maxlat="43.92" maxlon="-78.9999997"/>
    <node id="699540" lat="43.6751621" lon="-79.361332" version="1"/>
    <node id="699569" lat="43.7247576" lon="-79.3302633" version="1"/>
    <node id="1497736" lat="43.731285" lon="-79.3304523" version="1"/>
    <node id="1497764" lat="43.7412456" lon="-79.332082" version="1"/>
    <node id="1497766" lat="43.7418685" lon="-79.3321184" version="1"/>
    <node id="1497768" lat="43.7450436" lon="-79.3327357" version="1"/>
    <node id="1497773" lat="43.7459924" lon="-79.3329589" version="1"/>
    <node id="1497776" lat="43.747316" lon="-79.3332228" version="1"/>
    <node id="1497778" lat="43.7484115" lon="-79.3333255" version="1"/>
```

and my code:

```
import re
contador = 0

pattern = re.compile("node")

with open('toronto1.txt') as text:
print("leu Arquivo")
with open('saida.txt', 'w') as saida:
    print("criou arquivo")
    for text_line in text:
        comparacao = re.search(pattern, text_line)
        if comparacao is not None:
            node_line = text_line
            split_id = re.findall(r"[\w']+", node_line)
            saida.write(split_id[2]+'\n')           
            contador = contador + 1
    print contador
    saida.close()
text.close()

a = split_id[2]

print node_line
print split_id
print a
```

thx for the help.

Comment: Fix your indentation, please.

Comment: Probably because the list returned by `re.findall` is only finding a single match, so your list will only have a single element. I am unsure what you are expecting...

Comment: Stop trying to parse XML with a regex and use a DOM parser instead. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't understand the edit history. It looks like you've sprung an XML into life? What am I missing?

Comment: @roganjosh I had to wrap it in "code" or else it was being interpreted as HTML to do actual formatting.

Comment: First time using stackoverflow, sorry about indentation, i edited.
Looking for DIM parcer. thx you all

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, I did not know that. Looking at the initial question, I though it had been forgotten to be included.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is my list after de re.findall: ['node', 'id', '365507731', 'lat', '43', '7209752', 'lon', '79', '5030589', 'version', '1']

Comment: I guess `a = split_id[2]` is only giving you 1497778 which is the last id value, to get all ids print `a = split_id[2]` inside the for loop. cause split_id is changed for every line.

Comment: @Mimx yeah, i put this a = split_id[2] to test if the last one is catch, and it is! But if i put it inside de loop, i'll get the same error "index out of range". Do you have any ideia why?

Comment: @Mimx thank you so much, it was the only one who really tried to help me. You rock!

Comment: @Mimx The identention on this page was a error on the post, my identention on the code is right. Btw, i found the error, when the code find a line like: <tag k="created_by" v="JOSM"/> his send the error "out of range", but the strange is that on the "if comparacao is not None" should ignore that line. 
Now idk what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are getting a file that has only one big line and you are using the /n to close the loop so you only get that once.

Do as someone else told you and parse it the way it is supposed to.